# VirtualBox shared folders returning file not found when loading over HTTP

Tags: nginx, virtualbox, vagrant

Hi I have a VirtualBox image which I am starting with vagrant and mounting two shared folders.

The folders mount without a problem and are visible when I SSH to the guest machine, but when I try to `curl localhost` I get "file not found."

The shared folder is being mounted as the webroot for Nginx, if I point Nginx at a different webroot (guest file system) it works fine, and serves content.

I have tried different permission on Nginx, php-fpm and also ownership of the mount but still always get file not found.

I have tried as suggested here: https://serverfault.com/questions/425608/using-a-mounted-ntfs-share-with-nginx but no luck.

Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by Selinux blocking the Nginx server from accessing the shared folder. I just disabled SElinux as this is a development box rather then creating a rule to allow Nginx to access the files.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you expand your answer a little to provide more explanation to help others with a similar problem?

Comment: I can try!  Selinux was blocking the Nginx server from accessing the shared folder.  I just disabled SElinux as this is a development box rather then creating a rule to allow Nginx to access the files.

Answer (score 0):

are you doing your `curl localhost` from within vagrant environment or your main machine?
If you're doing it from your main machine, your port forwarding might not be enabled or your guest port 80 (vagrant) is mapped to some other port on host (i.e. 8080). If that's the case, you'll need to do `curl localhost:8080`

Also, make sure that your nginx is in fact running. It could happen that nginx is misconfigured and fails to start or that it is configured to listen on some other port.

Comment: hi I am doing the curl from the vagrant environment.  Nginx is running and so is php-fpm as it works fine if I repoint nginx root to a local directory rather than the mount.

Comment: Anything in the nginx logs?

Comment: Nginx Log: 

`2015/07/02 08:34:02 [crit] 1472#0: *1 stat() "/var/www/html/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.2.2, server: someurl.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
2`

Comment: perfect. that means that your file permissions are not correct... what are the permissions on your host for that folder and on the guest for that mount?